# Spring Boot @Aspect Logging

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logging, aspect

I tried to use @Aspect for logging all request and response. If my endpoint has @RequestBody my code is working, but my get endpoints has not @RequestBody and I can't see logs.  is that any explanation for this situation?

My class like that;

```
@Aspect
@Component
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__({@Autowired, @NotNull}))
public class AspectLogging {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Pointcut("@annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping) || @annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping)")
    public void annotationPointCutDefinition() {

    }

    @Pointcut("execution(* *(com.dux.secondwallet.api.v3.pay.merchant.*))")
    public void atExecution() {
    }

    @Before("annotationPointCutDefinition() && atExecution()")
    public void endpointBefore(JoinPoint p) {
        Object[] signatureArgs = p.getArgs();
        if (Objects.nonNull(signatureArgs) && signatureArgs.length > 0) {
            log.info("Request object: " + signatureArgs[0]);
        }
    }

    @AfterReturning(pointcut = "annotationPointCutDefinition() && atExecution()", returning = "returnValue")
    public void endpointAfterReturning(Object returnValue) {
        try {
            log.info("Response object:" + objectMapper.writeValueAsString(returnValue));
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }


    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "annotationPointCutDefinition() && atExecution()", throwing = "e")
    public void endpointAfterThrowing(JoinPoint p, Exception e) throws Exception {
        e.printStackTrace();
        log.error(p.getTarget().getClass().getSimpleName() + " " + p.getSignature().getName() + " " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Example controller; getRequest method not logging, postRequest logging.

```
 @Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v3/")
public class MyController {

    @GetMapping("/balances")//not before and after logging
    public List<java.lang.String> getRequest() {
        return Collections.singletonList("TEST");
    }

    @PostMapping("/limits")//its logging
    public TransactionLimitResponse postRequest(@Valid @RequestBody TransactionLimitRequest transactionLimitRequest) {
        return TransactionLimitResponse.builder()
                .currency("EUR")
                .type("TYPE")
                .min(100)
                .max(1000)
                .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your aspect looks for an argument in the method signature, and skips logging if there isn't one.

Comment: @Taylor how can ı pass that ? I wanna saw header or something else before request and also after request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all I want to ask you what do you want to log?

the purpose of your aspect code is to log method parameters, And You don't have any parameter on @GetMapping method.

so your aspect method is  successfully triggered for @GetMapping too. But just check if condition and pass it. It is quite normal that you can't see logs.

apply the changes below it will work:

```
@Pointcut("@annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping)")
//@Pointcut("@annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping) || @annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping))")
public void getMapping() {

}

@Pointcut("@annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping)")
//@Pointcut("@annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping) || @annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping))")
public void postMapping() {

}


 @Pointcut("execution(* *(..)) && within(com.dux.secondwallet.api.v3.pay.merchant.*))")
    public void atExecution() {
    }

@Before("(getMapping() || postMapping()) && atExecution()")
public void endpointBefore(JoinPoint p) {
    log.info("ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss");
    Object[] signatureArgs = p.getArgs();
    if (Objects.nonNull(signatureArgs) && signatureArgs.length > 0) {
        log.info("Request object: " + signatureArgs[0]);
    }else{
        log.info("log for get");
    }
}
```

`execution(* *(..))` : this is for your method signature.

`within(com.dux.secondwallet.api.v3.pay.merchant.*)` this is package restriction.

Comment: First I wanna saw header or something else before request. I say that before.
if my aspect code purpose is to log method parameters can you say how my aspect code triggered @GetMapping  ?
 Which if condition are you talking about ?

Comment: @Rhmn61 I have updated my answer. You can run it now.

Answer (score 1):

Your Pointcut is not well defined. With `@Pointcut("execution(* com.dux.secondwallet.api.v3.pay.merchant.*.*(..))")` the Pointcut will match all methods within the classes under the defined package.

**Hints**

Beside that you should use `@Configuration` for the Aspect-Configuration class instead of `@Component`. Furthermore by using `@NonNull` on the instance field you can skip the `@RequiredArgsConstructor` configuration.